# "segmentation fault" when assigning values to a specific position in a dynamically allocated matrix

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I did this plenty of times but suddenly I can't get over this error. I've got a simple input.txt file with this structure:

```
3 4
2 1 1
1 2 3
8 3 3
```

Where the first line is basically the matrix's size and then follows value row col each line. I'm using calloc so the matrix is set to 0 and then reading the file I replace the values and their position. And exactly in the **readFile()** function i get "*segmentation fault*", I guess when it tries to replace the values in the matrix.
As a consequence what I'm trying to get is this:

```
2 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 8 0
```

```c
void readSize(FILE *fp, int *rows, int *cols) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", rows, cols);
}

void readFile (FILE *fp, int **A) {
    int val, row, col;
    val = row = col = 0;

    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, fp);        //* skip first line

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &val, &row, &col);        
        A[row][col] = val;    

        val = row = col = 0;
    }
}

int **allocMatrix(int m, int n) {
    int **A = (int** )calloc(m, sizeof(int* ));
    for( int i = 0; i < m; i++) *(A + i) = (int* )calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    
    if (A == NULL) {
        handleErr(ALLOC_ERR);
        free(A);
    }

    return A;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen(INPUT, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) handleErr(READ_FILE_ERR);

    int **A, m, n;      //! m -> rows | n -> cols

    readSize(fp, &m, &n);
    A = allocMatrix(m, n);

    readFile(fp, A);
    fclose(fp);
    printMatrix(A, m, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). And *always* check if `fscanf` was successful. `while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &val, &row, &col) == 3)`

Comment: Aside: with `if (A == NULL)` you are too late - you have already dereferenced it (and the program continues anyway).

Comment: The row and col indices in your file are 1-based, but your C program treats them as zero-based. There is no row "three" / `A[3]` in your matrix. You should consider this when assigning the values. And your reading function should know how big the matrix is so that it can catch bad input.

Comment: OK got it, now it works. Thank you all.
Anyways, beyond the misusage of feof, the main problem that I didn't noticed before was actually the indexes starting from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has several minor mistakes. The bug you are specifically looking for appears to be `A[row][col] = val;`. Since you've allocated a pointer table of size 3x4, you cannot access array item `[3][3]` in that array, since arrays are 0-indexed in C. Your input file appears to be 1-indexed.

One way to rewrite the code into using proper 2D arrays instead would be something like this:

```c
readSize(fp, &m, &n);
int (*A)[n+1] = allocMatrix(m,n);
...
free(A);
```

With the function properly rewritten as:

```
void* allocMatrix(int m, int n) 
{
   int (*A)[n+1] = calloc( 1, sizeof(int[m+1][n+1]) );
   if(A == NULL)
   {
     handleErr(ALLOC_ERR);;
   }
   return A;
}
```

You can rewrite the other functions to work with 2D arrays too, for example:

```
void readFile (FILE *fp, int x, int y, int A[x][y])
```

Then ideally check if the read `row` and `cols` are inside the bounds of `x` and `y` before accessing that location.

You should also check the result of `fscanf` instead of incorrectly using `while(!feof(fp))`. In case `fscanf` fail you currently still try to access the data read, which is wrong.